# How to generate ID Token for Cloud Run Service in Dart?

Tags: dart, http, google-oauth, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have a project that performs authentication when sending API request to Cloud Run Service, but seems like the ID token changes continually, so from time to time, the request headers become invalid.

Is there a way to generate ID token from service account in dart? If yes, can you provide code implementation?

Comment: Can you translate from another language into Dart? There are examples in Python, Node.js, Go, etc. I cannot write code in Dart, but I know the low-level details on how to generate tokens and I can help you with the code you write. Here is an example for [Python](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/).

Comment: Here is a Google [document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token) with more examples. If your code is running on a Google Cloud compute service (Functions, Run, Compute Engine, etc) you can fetch tokens from the metadata service. That document has more details on different methods.